# Simple Validation Lead to a Infinite While Loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, while-loop

I'm currently making a scoring system for an event and I'm having  trouble using while loops as way to validate user input. For example I want to force the user enter their name so it can be added to a spot for a sport like tennis which I used a dictionary for. Everytime I am done asking them for their user input the while loop keeps apearing leading to a never ending while loop. Here's what I've done.

````
  ```solo_player = {
"Contestant 1":{"Player 1":[],"Score":[],"Event":[]},
"Contestant 2":{"Player 2 ":[],"Score":[],"Event":[]},
"Contestant 3":{"Player 3":[],"Score":[],"Event":[]},
"Contestant 4":{"Player 4":[],"Score":[],"Event":[]}}

 def individual():
  solo_name = False
  while not solo_name:
 solo_name = input("What is your name:")
 print(""" \nIndividual Menu and Available Spots\n
  1) Player 1
  2) Player 2
  3) Player 3
 \n4) Go back to Main Menu\n""")

 solo_menu = ["1","2","3","4"] #valid choices for this menu
 solo_menu = False
 while not solo_menu:
   solo_menu = input("Please enter your choice here:")

   if solo_menu == "1":
    solo_player["Contestant 1"]["Player 1"].append(solo_name)
    print(solo_player["Contestant 1"])
    print("Thank you for taking the spot of Player 1")
    solo_menu = True

   elif solo_menu == "2":
    solo_player["Contestant 2"]["Player 2"].append(solo_name)
    print(solo_player["Contestant 2"])
    print("Thank you for taking the spot of Player 2")
    solo_menu = True

    else: 
     print("Enter a value between 1-4)
     solo_menu = False```
````

My ideal output would be that the while loop will stop after I picked one spot from the available spots. Sorry for the long if/else statements I'm quite new to it so I don't know how to make it shorter

EDIT: I fixed the issue. It was caused by calling the individual func outside my menu def.

Comment: In the code you posted, the indentation is all wrong, so we can't really tell what the loop and functions are about exactly. 

Can you try and fix it by wrapping your code inside code blocks, via the three tick marks ` ?

Comment: ill try and fix

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Your posted code fails to run.  It hangs waiting for input -- don't expect us to enter test data.
Instead, simply hard-code a test case that causes the problem.

Comment: The code is not minimal; delete the extra cases, the initialization overhead.  You also have to test the smaller pieces of your program, so that we're concentrating on *one* problem.  A scan through your code shows at least three.

Comment: sorry for copying the whole code I'll try to make it shorter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I believe you are after.

A couple of changes:

1. Your while loops can contain the validation that you are wanting to perform as their condition. If your validation becomes more complex then you can consider moving back to a boolean to break the while loop, but it feels overly complex for your requirements.
2. Removal of the if statements. The whole idea of a dictionary is that you can specific a key and get a value, so having an `elif` for every potential key is overly cumbersome. Just concatenate the validated user input to derive the key.

---

```
solo_player = {
"Contestant 1":{"Player 1":[],"Score":[],"Event":[]},
"Contestant 2":{"Player 2":[],"Score":[],"Event":[]},
"Contestant 3":{"Player 3":[],"Score":[],"Event":[]},
"Contestant 4":{"Player 4":[],"Score":[],"Event":[]},
"Contestant 5":{"Player 5":[],"Score":[],"Event":[]},
"Contestant 6":{"Player 6":[],"Score":[],"Event":[]},
"Contestant 7":{"Player 7":[],"Score":[],"Event":[]}}


solo_name=""    
while solo_name == "":
    solo_name = input("What is your name:")
    print(""" \nIndividual Menu and Available Spots\n
        1) Player 1
        2) Player 2
        3) Player 3
        4) Player 4
        5) Player 5
        6) Player 6
        7) Player 7
        \8) Go back to Main Menu\n""")

#prompt for player slot
solo_menu_options = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"] #valid choices for this menu
solo_menu=""
while solo_menu not in solo_menu_options:
    solo_menu = input("Please enter your choice here:")    

solo_player["Contestant "+solo_menu]["Player "+solo_menu].append(solo_name)
print(solo_player["Contestant "+solo_menu])
print("Thank you for taking the spot of Player "+solo_menu)
```

Comment: What does solo_player ="" supposed to do exactly? I'm quite new to programming so Idk

Comment: I don't see `solo_player=""` in the code.

Comment: My bad I mean ```solo_menu=""``` on the answer you gave me

Comment: I seem to encounter the same problem as before when I tried using code

Comment: `solo_menu=""` just initializes the variable so it can be used in the loop (the first iteration would error since it would be like "while thing_that_doesnt_exist_at_all not in solo_menu_options:"